# Fill a board using rectangles and L shaped blocks with given size

Tags: python

This might be an easy problem, but I’m not quite getting it:

> Given a rectangular puzzle board and 10 puzzle pieces, determine which pieces will fill the puzzle grid. Pieces are shaped as either a rectangle or the letter “L.”
> Use the following rules in order to fill the puzzle board:
>
> 1. Pieces must be placed in the board from large to small. If multiple pieces have the same area, use the one with the largest width first.
> 2. The first puzzle piece is placed in the lower left hand corner of the grid. The following pieces are placed in the leftmost cell of the bottommost row where it will fit.
> 3. Continue to place pieces in the grid using the rules above until the grid is filled or no more pieces will fit.
>
> Print the pieces in the order they fit into the board; if the board cannot be completely filled, print “NONE”. Pieces cannot be rotated or flipped in any way. The largest puzzle board will be 9x9.
>
> Rectangular pieces are described by 2-character strings, the width followed by height. The “L” pieces are described by 3-character strings: width, height of the vertical part, the width of the vertical part; the base of the “L” has a height of 1.
>
> **INPUT**:  There will be 11 lines of input. The first line will contain the 10 puzzle pieces: 2-character or 3-character numeric strings. The remaining 10 lines will each contain 2 integers, representing the width and height, respectively, of the puzzle board. Use only rectangular pieces for the first 5 boards; the last 5 boards can use the “L” shaped puzzle pieces.
>
> **OUTPUT**: Print the pieces used to fill the puzzle board in the order they were used. If the board can’t be filled, print NONE.

Some examples

[image]

SAMPLE INPUT:

```
12, 22, 32, 23, 43, 31, 44, 33, 443, 11
7, 4
6, 3
3, 2
3, 5
2, 2
4, 4
3, 3
5, 3
6, 2
8, 4
```

SAMPLE OUTPUT:

```
44, 33, 31
43, 23
22, 12
33, 32
NONE
443, 12,11
32, 31
43,12, 11
32, 22, 12
44, 443, 12, 11
```

I tried to create a Width by Height 2D array filled with boolean and made it True when placed with block. However, it didn’t seem to work. I’m quite new to this type of question. Can someone please provide a solution or give a hint?

Comment: Answers to the question, as it currently is, will only be theoretical algorithms or suggestions. If possible, try to provide some boilerplate code that will set up the puzzle, to make it easier for others to get going with the main algorithm, rather than frustrating over how to print the rectangles and puzzle on console etc.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I added some example input and outputs to clarify the question.